# Default underlying storage size of Stack<T>

Tags: c#

I know that the `Stack<T>`'s underlying storage is `T[]`, but what is it's default size ?

Comment: See the .NET Reference Source for these kinds of questions. (Of course, this *isn't* a promise for other/future implementation behavior..)

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs,52293d65ba832461

Comment: or of course you could make one and use the debuggger to look at its insides

Comment: (FWIW, I often use ReSharpers Navigate - Decompiled Sources.)

Comment: My question is why do you want to know?

Comment: Do you mean size or capacity? Size depends on T, and is `sizeof(T) * defaultCapacity`.

Comment: The best answer to this question is "You do not need to know the answer to this question". If you want a specific initial capacity then explicitly provide it. If you don't then you don't need to know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The stack.cs file shows this information in System.Collections.Stack:

```
private const int _defaultCapacity = 10;
```

In System.Collections.Generic.Stack, the default is 4

```
private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;
```

Reference: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6

Comment: `Stack<T>` has a __defaultCapacity = 4;_ https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6

Comment: It is worth noting that although that is the value for `_defaultCapacity` when the `Stack<T>` is first created it has an empty array. It doesn't create an array that can contain items until you try to put something into it. So this could misleadingly imply that when you first create a `Stack<T>` that there is an array with space for four items which would be wrong.

Comment: true, but it might be more interesting why the values are different between generic and non-generic version...

Comment: @Ctznkane525: While maybe interesting I suspect still unanswerable and not actually useful so. You could always ask it as a question and see if anybody in the community is able to answer it though (but developer reasoning is often very hard to answer).

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you asked about the default **size** (not capacity) then the answer is **zero**.

De-compiling my version I saw this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1"/> class that is empty and has the default initial capacity.
/// </summary>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public Stack()
{
  this._array = Stack<T>._emptyArray;
  this._size = 0;
  this._version = 0;
}

private static T[] _emptyArray = new T[0];
```

But I'm not sure this is documented so your mileage my vary.

Comment: The "size" is the number of items, so it will be 0 for a new (empty) stack :}